# how to upload local image in react native app

Tags: react-native, file-upload

Hello I am trying to make avatar upload functionality in my react native app.

```
import React, {useCallback, useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  Image,
  FlatList,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';
import BackButton from '../../components/BackButton/BackButton';
import {width} from '../../utils/helpers';
import DefaultButton from '../../components/DefaultButton/DefaultButton';
import DocumentPicker from 'react-native-document-picker';
import NetworkManager from '../../services/network';
import Variables from '../../services/Variables';
import {openSuccessToast} from '../../utils/successToast';
import {openToast} from '../../utils/toast';
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import {setPersonalInfo} from '../../reducers/PersonalInfo/PersonalInfo.action';
import {selectAuth} from '../../reducers/auth/auth.selector';
const avatarPngsArray = [
  {id: 1, item: require('../../images/1.png')},
  {id: 40, item: require('../../images/40.png')},
  {id: 2, item: require('../../images/2.png')},
  {id: 3, item: require('../../images/3.png')},
  {id: 4, item: require('../../images/4.png')},
  {id: 5, item: require('../../images/5.png')},
  {id: 6, item: require('../../images/6.png')},
  {id: 7, item: require('../../images/7.png')},
  {id: 8, item: require('../../images/8.png')},
  {id: 9, item: require('../../images/9.png')},
  {id: 10, item: require('../../images/10.png')},
  {id: 11, item: require('../../images/11.png')},
  {id: 12, item: require('../../images/12.png')},
  {id: 13, item: require('../../images/13.png')},
  {id: 14, item: require('../../images/14.png')},
  {id: 15, item: require('../../images/15.png')},
  {id: 16, item: require('../../images/16.png')},
  {id: 17, item: require('../../images/17.png')},
  {id: 18, item: require('../../images/18.png')},
  {id: 19, item: require('../../images/19.png')},
  {id: 20, item: require('../../images/20.png')},
  {id: 21, item: require('../../images/21.png')},
  {id: 22, item: require('../../images/22.png')},
  {id: 23, item: require('../../images/23.png')},
  {id: 24, item: require('../../images/24.png')},
  {id: 25, item: require('../../images/25.png')},
  {id: 26, item: require('../../images/26.png')},
  {id: 27, item: require('../../images/27.png')},
  {id: 28, item: require('../../images/28.png')},
  {id: 29, item: require('../../images/29.png')},
  {id: 30, item: require('../../images/30.png')},
  {id: 31, item: require('../../images/31.png')},
  {id: 32, item: require('../../images/32.png')},
  {id: 33, item: require('../../images/33.png')},
  {id: 34, item: require('../../images/34.png')},
  {id: 35, item: require('../../images/35.png')},
  {id: 36, item: require('../../images/36.png')},
  {id: 37, item: require('../../images/37.png')},
  {id: 38, item: require('../../images/38.png')},
  {id: 39, item: require('../../images/39.png')},
];

const randomAvatar = Math.floor(Math.random() * 40) + 1;
const gap = (width - 300) / 4;

const AvatarsScreen = ({navigation}) => {
  const s = styles();
  const [activeAvatar, setActiveAvatar] = useState(null);
  const [singleFile, setSingleFile] = useState(null);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [localFileLoading, setLocalFileLoading] = useState(false);
  const [localLoading, setLocalLoading] = useState(false);
  const {currentRole} = useSelector(selectAuth);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      if (singleFile) {
        await postAvatar(singleFile);
      }
    })();
  }, [singleFile]);

  const selectLocalAvatar = item => setActiveAvatar(item.id);

  const pickImage = useCallback(async () => {
    setLocalLoading(true);
    try {
      const selectedImage = avatarPngsArray.find(
        avatar => avatar.id === activeAvatar,
      );
      const imageData = Image.resolveAssetSource(selectedImage.item);
      const imageDataWithName = Object.assign(imageData, {
        name: `avatar-${selectedImage.id}.png`,
      });
      await postAvatar(imageDataWithName);
    } catch (e) {
      // openToast('ERROR:', e);
    }
  }, [activeAvatar]);

  const postAvatar = async fileUri => {
    try {
      const formData = new FormData();
      if (fileUri) {
        formData.append('files', {
          uri: fileUri.uri,
          type: 'multipart/form-data',
          name: fileUri.name,
        });
      }

      const authToken = `Bearer ${NetworkManager._getToken()}`;
      const url = `${Variables.API_URL}personalinformation?role=${currentRole}`;

      const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          Authorization: authToken,
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        },
        body: formData,
      });

      if (response.ok) {
        setLocalLoading(false);
        setLocalFileLoading(false);
        setSingleFile(null);
        dispatch(setPersonalInfo());
        if (navigation.canGoBack()) navigation.goBack();
      } else {
        setLocalLoading(false);
        setLocalFileLoading(false);
        console.log(response);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      setSingleFile(null);
      setLocalLoading(false);
      setLocalFileLoading(false);
      console.error('Error during file upload:', error);
    }
  };

  const renderItem = useCallback(
    ({item}) => {
      return (
        <TouchableOpacity
          activeOpacity={0.9}
          style={{borderRadius: 50}}
          onPress={() => selectLocalAvatar(item)}>
          <Image
            source={item.item}
            style={[s.imageInactive, item.id === activeAvatar && s.imageActive]}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      );
    },
    [activeAvatar],
  );

  const selectFile = async () => {
    setLocalFileLoading(true);
    try {
      const res = await DocumentPicker.pick({
        type: [DocumentPicker.types.images],
      });
      setSingleFile(res);
    } catch (err) {
      setSingleFile(null);
      if (DocumentPicker.isCancel(err)) {
      } else {
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <View style={s.header}>
        <BackButton
          onPress={() => {
            if (navigation.canGoBack()) navigation.goBack();
          }}
        />
      </View>
      <Text style={s.heading}>choose avatar or upload photo</Text>
      <View style={{flex: 1, marginTop: 32}}>
        <FlatList
          data={avatarPngsArray}
          renderItem={renderItem}
          numColumns={3}
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        />
      </View>
      <View style={{marginVertical: 12, rowGap: 10}}>
        <DefaultButton
          text="upload from device"
          isUpperCase
          bgColor="rgba(173, 202, 255, 1)"
          fontColor="rgba(74, 80, 92, 1)"
          onPress={selectFile}
          loading={localFileLoading}
          isDisabled={localFileLoading}
        />
        <DefaultButton
          text="save"
          isUpperCase
          onPress={pickImage}
          isDisabled={!activeAvatar || localLoading}
          loading={localLoading}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default AvatarsScreen;

const styles = () =>
  StyleSheet.create({
    header: {
      flexDirection: 'row',
      padding: 16,
      alignItems: 'center',
    },
    heading: {
      color: 'rgba(29, 36, 51, 1)',
      fontSize: 14,
      fontWeight: '500',
      textTransform: 'uppercase',
      marginTop: 16,
      marginLeft: 16,
    },
    imageInactive: {
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      marginLeft: gap,
      marginBottom: gap,
    },
    imageActive: {
      borderWidth: 8,
      borderColor: 'rgba(93, 148, 250, 1)',
      borderRadius: 50,
    },
  });
```

Images which I choose from device are being uploaded normally, but when I try to upload local image, for example {id: 1, item: require('../../images/1.png')}, android uploads it successfully and specifies correct content-type: 'multipart/form-data', that backend takes. But when i try to upload this local avatar from iOS, it magically cuts off 'multipart/form-data' and eventually content-type:  is specified, in this case backend throws an exception of content-type is null and returns status code of 500.

Comment: Are you running the app via a development build locally, or via expo?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of styling the `<Image/>` component directly, you can try wrapping the `<Image/>` component with `<View>` and "styling" both. Or you can give the width and height of the `<TouchableOpacity/>` component that wraps your `<Image/>` component. I'm not sure it will work, but at least it's an idea.